# Force chrome not to convert dot to comma in input type = number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, google-chrome

I have an angular application where in I have used input type = "number" where in I get the value from a service. The service gives me these numbers in decimal points Eg: 0.5, 0.6 , 0.7.
So my textbox shows 0.5, 0.6 , 0.7
But when I change the browser language to French, the textbox is showing 0,5 as comma is used in french for decimals.

```
<input type="number" value=0.5>

Output:French language: 0,5
       English language: 0.5
```

I do not want this conversion of dot to comma. Is there any way in angularjs or javascript where I can stop the browser from converting dot to comma?
I do not want to change the type of input as there are lot of validations.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a **lang** attribute to the HTML tag, like so:

```
<html lang="en">
```

Comment: I have already added this. But still the conversion of dot to comma happens.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following directive. If it solve your problem.

```
directive('smartFloat', function() {
     var FLOAT_REGEXP = /^\-?\d+((\.|\,)\d+)?$/;
     return {
         require: 'ngModel',
         link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
             ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
                 if (FLOAT_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
                     ctrl.$setValidity('float', true);
                     if(typeof viewValue === "number")
                         return viewValue;
                     else
                         return parseFloat(viewValue.replace(',', '.'));
                 } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('float', false);
                    return undefined;
                 }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And use it as follows:

```
<input type="text" smartFloat value="0.5" />
```

I found this from this link: http://www.wmyl.se/en/blog/comma-dot-input-typenumber-mess/

Comment: html tag already has the lang="en". But still I tried the above approach. The conversion still happens.

Comment: There is no [*requirement*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.1) for a client to take any notice of the *lang* attribute: "*…the lang attribute **may** be used by a user agent…*" (my emphasis).

Comment: Yes you are right it is not working with lang="en". Updated the answer though I did not tried this answer.